# Confused about char arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I am trying to implement the functions below, but printing out the output of Printme(), the program that freezes . Any ideas why?

```
int main() 
{
   for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
   {
        cout<< PrintMe()[i];
   }
   return 0;
}

char * PrintMe() {
  char str[12];
  strncpy (str, "hello world", 11);
  str[11] = 0;
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code invokes **Undefined Behaviour** as you are returning a pointer to a temporary.
As soon `PrintMe` ends its execution, `str` becomes destroyed. Thus the pointer your accessing with `PrintMe()[i]` is invalid.

To fix this you have to return a heap allocated string (no automatic storage duration). But dont forget to destroy it afterwards:

```
char * PrintMe() {
  char* str = new char[12];
  strncpy (str, "hello world", 11);
  str[11] = 0;
  return str;
}
```

---

```
char* str = PrintMe();

for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
   cout<< str[i];
}

delete[] str;
```

Or as you're writing c++ nontheless, why dont you go with a `std::string`?

Answer (score 0):

The program has undefined behaviour because function `PrintMe` returns a pointer to the first element of a local array that will be destroyed after exiting the function. So the pointer will not be valid.

Change the function the following way that to get the predicted result

```
char * PrintMe() {
  static char str[12];
  strncpy (str, "hello world", 11);
  str[11] = 0;
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PrintMe function, you are returning a pointer to a local variable.  This is undefined behavior:

```
char* PrintMe() {
    char str[12];
    //...
    return str;  // cannot do this, UB.
}
```

This works if you change the return type to std::string

```
std::string PrintMe() {
    char str[12];
    //...
    return str;  
}
```

The reason why the above now works is that a std::string is being constructed from the local array and returned instead of the local variable.